# substring to get a space j2ME

Tags: java, java-me, substring

I have a string that end with a space like this :

```
String s="somthing= "
```

I want to get that space so I do :

```
s.substring(s.indexOf("=")+1).trim()
```

but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to remove that whitespace??

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question. It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want to get a String only containing the whitespace? And what is your definition of "does not work"?

Comment: By the way: `trim()`ing a String containing whitespace only ... what will you get? I guess the empty String. Always. Is **that** your goal?

Comment: if String s="somthing=A" I can get the A using that code but if String s="somthing= " I can't gat the space " " I get empty string I want to get " " as a result

Comment: @user1662513.. Then remove that `trim` from the end.. `trim` removes the whitespaces from the end of strings, and you want `whitespace`. So you can't use trim..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not modifying your string `s`, just the substring. The specs say that `substring()`

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

The `trim()` method affects the substring, not `s`, so that's why it doesn't work. By doing `s.trim()` directly you'll remove the whitespaces at the end (and beginning) of `s`, but watch out since this method also returns a new ("a copy" says the specs) `String`, so try doing `s = s.trim();`.

Comment: One might want to add that the single-param `substring` method is probably not doing, what the op expected.

Comment: @Fildor Indeed!. Also he might be misunderstanding `trim()` too, if he wants to invoke the method on the whitespace directly to remove it.

Comment: @user1662513 I see, no problem. Keep it up, pal.